# Why do i get IndexError: list index out of range while parsing dictionary?

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, transpose

I am trying to pick a table from two different dictionary but after the for loop given below, i get an error as "IndexError: list index out of range" .

My dictionary ;

```
>>> file_dict
{'NODES': ['BSHTAS1', 'GB-vMTAS', 'GBHTAS1', 'GBMTAS1', 'GBZLRF', 'MBHTAS01', 'MNDHTAS', 'SGT-vMTAS', 'SOGZLRF'],
 'KPIS': [['VoLTE MO Voice Connection Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Voice Answer Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Voice Call Drop Times(times)', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Video Connection Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Video Answer Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Video Call Drop Times(times)', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Voice Connection Rate(%)', 'NOK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Voice Answer Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Voice Call Drop Times(times)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Video Connection Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Video Answer Rate(%)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Video Call Drop Times(times)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MO Request Times(times)', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK'],
          ['VoLTE MT Request Times(times)', 'OK', 'NOK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK', 'OK']
         ]}
```

And i would like to make the headers the keys below ;

```
>>> file_dict["KPIS"][0][0]
'VoLTE MO Voice Connection Rate(%)'
```

Here is my loop. Could you please tell me where is my error ? Thanks a lot..

```
rows = []
headers = ["Kpis"]
for filename in file_list:
    file_content = open('{}'.format(filename), 'r').read()
    file_string = json.loads(file_content)
    # convert string to dictionary
    file_dict = eval(file_string)
    if "KPIS" in file_dict:
        ind = 0
        for eachkpi in file_dict["KPIS"]:
            t = [eachkpi]
            for eachnode in file_dict["KPIS"]:
                if eachnode[0][0] not in headers:
                    headers.append(eachnode[0][0])
                t.append(eachnode[ind + 1])
            rows.append(t)
            ind = ind + 1
```

The error message ;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 13, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
>>>
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: Oh, No. The *full* error traceback would list the text of the line of code which produced the error.

Comment: Print the index before using it to access something. You will get to know the issue

Comment: I think here `t.append(eachnode[ind + 1])` the index eventually gets bigger than `len(eachnode)`.

Comment: how can i put a control for index size here ?

Answer (score 0):

A quick note due to the comments ; 
I do not receive error when i do this in transposed way ;

```
rows = []
headers = ["Nodes"]
for filename in file_list:
    file_content = open('{}'.format(filename), 'r').read()
    file_string = json.loads(file_content)
    # convert string to dictionary
    file_dict = eval(file_string)
    if "NODES" in file_dict:
        ind = 0
        for enode in file_dict["NODES"]:
            t = [enode]
            for ekpi in file_dict["KPIS"]:
                if ekpi[0] not in headers:
                    headers.append(ekpi[0])
                t.append(ekpi[ind + 1])
            rows.append(t)
            ind = ind + 1
```